# Vue v-for with variable range not working

Tags: loops, vue.js, range, v-for

`totalLoops = 3;`

Expected output:
`1 2 3`

Working:

`<div v-for="i in 3">{{ i }}</div>`

Not working:

`<div v-for="i in totalLoops">{{ i }}</div>`

I have searched and tried different solutions but none of them work for me. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Sorry, bad question. This code is working properly. I found the problem was in other piece of code.

Comment: It [works](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8ZGl2IHYtZm9yPVwiaSBpbiB0b3RhbExvb3BzXCI+e3sgaSB9fTwvZGl2PlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbjxzY3JpcHQ+XG5leHBvcnQgZGVmYXVsdCB7XG4gIGRhdGEoKXtcbiAgICByZXR1cm57XG4gICAgICB0b3RhbExvb3BzIDogMTAsXG4gICAgfVxuICB9LFxufVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG4ifQ==)

Comment: u_U' After few hours, I just realized the problem was with the source for the totalLoops. I was so obsessed with the loop that I didn't notice it... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to add your `:key=`.
Anyways your code seems to be ok and it's working at my end

```
<div v-for="i in 3" :key="i">{{ i }}</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is working now. I found that the problem is in the other side, with the source of the variable itself. Thanks for the key comment ;)